# TypeError: Date can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Basically this:

```
1.9.3p0 :024 > 2.day + Date.today
```

Gives an error:

```
TypeError: Date can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Can anyone explain why this is hapenning and how to add 2 days/months to a current day

Comment: Rails screwed minds all around. People! Wake UP!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn it around.

```
Date.today + 2.days
```

**Followup**

`2.days` returns a `Fixnum`, which has a `.+()` method, which expects another numeric type, of which `Date` is not.  `Date` has a `.+()` method that accepts `Fixnum` and other numeric types.

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer.  Basically, `Fixnum` expects a numeric type as a parameter to the `+` method.  `Date` is not a numeric type.

Comment: You can use `2.days` or `2`.  The first one is more explicit than the second one, but it works.  It could make readability better since you can also have `Date.today + 2.months` or `Time.now + 6.hours`.

Comment: Is that changed in newer versions of Rails? Still using an old version where 2.day will give seconds, and a Date should be added with days (I think)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure.  I've been using `.days` for years now, so I am not sure when it would have changed.

Comment: And you are sure that you use it together with a Date? (for a Time object it should work). In my console: `(Date.today + 2.day).to_s` `#> "2486-01-19"`

Comment: This is what I get from Rails 3.2.8: `(Date.today + 2.days).to_s
=> "2012-12-11"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20859/discussion-between-244an-and-sean-hill)